# Metric space where every bounded sequence is contained in a compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that, for every bounded sequence $(x_n)$ taking values in $X$, there exists a compact set $K\subseteq X$ such that $x_n \in K$ for all $n$. Do such spaces have a particular name?

This includes the case of metric spaces with the Heine--Borel property, i.e., spaces where every closed bounded set is compact. In our case the closure of the image $\{x_n:n \ge 1\}$ is closed and bounded, hence compact. However, is the above class strictly larger than the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two classes are the same. Suppose every bounded sequence is contained in some compact set. Let $K$ be closed and bounded. Then any sequence in $K$ is contained in some compact set and this implies that there is  a convergent subsequence. But then $K $ is sequentially compact which implies that it is compact.

Comment: Indeed, in metric spaces sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness. That was very easy, thank you.